# Z3 Doesn't Recognize Insert and Nil Without Type

Tags: z3

In the following code, Z3 doesn't recognize `nil` in line 1 until `xs` is declared to be `List`. How to solve this? Is there an `import`/`include` like construct in Z3/SMT-LIB2?

```
(assert (= nil nil))          ; (error "line 1 column 12: unknown constant nil")
(declare-const xs (List Int))
(assert (= nil nil))          ; OK after declare-const List Int
```

Testing both from the file or using `z3 -in` will see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general shortcoming of the SMT-Lib standard, unfortunately. The only way to bring symbols to scope is via `set-logic` declarations, and the list of those logics is fixed. When individual solvers (such as z3) implement new decision procedures they have to bring in the symbols in an ad hoc way. It appears z3 only brings the symbol `nil` into scope when it sees `List` in a declaration; which is error-prone to say the least.

This has come up various times in discussions, alas there doesn't seem to be anyone with enough motivation (myself included) to make a concrete proposal and work out all the details. See here, for instance: http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/smt-lib/2015/000862.html, where a suggestion was made to move away from fixed logic declarations to more `import` style specifications.

So, you're pretty much stuck with declaring a `List` first it seems, given the current state of things. Hopefully, SMTLib will evolve in ways to support new features in more flexible ways in the future.